# How do I move the ball on a particular angle in the Android canvas?

Tags: android

How do I move the ball on a particular angle in the Android canvas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might look at this example. Was very helpful to me for moving (rotating in my case) a dial  on a canvas.

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/

Comment: Thankq for your reply chrispix.have u see my post clearly.i am looking for move a ball in particular angle. like move ball top to bottom.left 2 right and cross direction on screen like that.can you pl share your idea regarding this